# Proving exponential operator is linear.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I think we're asked to prove that $e^{(aT(x)+b)}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{T^k(ax+b)}{k!}$. However, I think I might be interpreting it wrong.

My try:

For $G(x)=aT(x)+b$, we have $G^k(x)=a^kT^k(x)+b\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}a^j$, so,

$e^{G(x)}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{a^kT^k(x)+b\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}a^j}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{T^k(a^kx+b\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}a^j)}{k!}$.

Which is completely different from what I was expecting...

So, what's the correct interpretation of saying that the exponential is linear?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to prove that $e^A(c_1v_1+c_2v_2)=c_1e^Av_1+c_2e^Av_2$.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for the comment. ;)

Comment: @JohnB by the way John, for $e^{T-T}=e^0$. but how do we prove that $e^0=1$? or is $T-T$ not identified with the operator $0$?